# Encrypting with generic GPG key in gpg4win

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

One of our business partners has a PGP domain key where the key is valid for encryption to any email address of the business.

The user id of the key is like `everybody@example.com` - and for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to use gpg4win / Kleopatra to use this key to encrypt the email address `peter.paul@example.com`.

Comment: Are you doing this through a specific email app, or are you encrypting the text through Kleopatra manually and then pasting it into email?

Comment: If encrypting outside of a desktop email program, `gpg` would be used directly _(see [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gpg-to-encrypt-and-sign-messages#encrypt-and-decrypt-messages-with-gpg))_, whereas if using a desktop email program like Outlook 365, use the Gpg4Win add-in via the _Secure_ button on the toolbar that's shown when writing an email

Answer (score 0):

If you're encrypting the text manually, then the actual recipient does not matter, because you're not encrypting a whole email message – only generic text. Just choose the PGP key from the list.

If you're sending the message normally and relying on the mail app to automatically choose the key, define an alias in your `gpg.conf`. GnuPG has the `group` option which allows defining recipient aliases, either as short names or whole addresses:

```
group peter.paul@example.com = everybody@example.com
```

A single, company-wide shared encryption key is a rather strange setup – most importantly, it seems prone to leaking. (Even for centrally-managed encryption, there are better ways.)